# watchgroup doesn't fire but watch does

Tags: angularjs

I can't get my watchgroup to fire when my model `scnListing` changes but it will fire when it in a watch...My other two models (`chartTyp`, `yAxistm`) in the group do trigger the watchgroup but changes in scnListing do not...

```
//this does work when scnListing changes
$scope.$watch('scnListing', function(model) {
    $scope.modelAsJson = angular.toJson(model, true);
    console.log("model: ", model);
}, true);


//this does not work when scnListing changes, but works when the other two do
$scope.$watchGroup(['yAxistm', 'chrtTyp', 'scnListing'], function(newval, oldval) {

    console.log('yAxistm val: ', newval[0]);
    console.log('chartTyp val: ', newval[1]);
    console.log('scenarios: ', newval[2]);
});
```

----EDIT-------

full code:

```
cloudJumper.controller("comparisonReportsController", function($scope, $rootScope, Scenario, Rpt_scn_cost_v, Rpt_scn_app_count_v, Rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_timeseries_ftprnt_v) {

    var selected_scenarios = $rootScope.selected_scenarios;
    console.info('Selected Scenarios: ', selected_scenarios); // for testing

    $scope.myScenarios = Scenario.find();
    $scope.scnListing =[]

    function get_scns () { 

        return Scenario.find().$promise.then(function(response){ 

            var scnList = response

            var scnLables = {
                "selected": null,
                "lists": {
                    "List of Scenarios": [],
                    "Selected Scenarios": []
                }
            };

            for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++) {    
                scnLables.lists["List of Scenarios"].push(response[i].scenario_desc);
            };

            console.log("scnLables: ", JSON.stringify(scnLables));

            return scnLables;

        });

    };


    get_scns().then(function(scnLables){ 

        $scope.scnListing = scnLables;

    });

    // Scenarion Comparison Of Cost Line Graph 
    var scn_cst_chart_data = [];
    var costByScn2 = []; // graph data  
    var cstScnLvl = [];
    var cntScnLvl = [];

    $scope.yAxistm = 'yr';
    $scope.chrtTyp = 'multiBarChart';

//    $scope.$watch('scnListing', function(newval, oldval) {
//        
//        console.log("model: ", newval);
//        
//    },true);
//    
//    $scope.dropCallback = function(event, index, item, external, type, allowedType) {
//        
//        
//        console.log("dropped");
//    };




    $scope.$watchGroup(['yAxistm', 'chrtTyp', 'scnListing'], function(newval, oldval) {

        console.log('yAxistm val: ', newval[0]);
        console.log('chartTyp val: ', newval[1]);
        console.log('scenarios: ', newval[2]);

        //does stuff

    });
});
```

here is whats in the markup too:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row advancedDemo" style="border-radius: 5px solid black">
            <div ng-repeat="(listName, list) in scnListing.lists" class="col-md-12">
                <h4 align="center" style="border-top: 1pt solid black">{{ listName }}</h4>
                <div dnd-list="list" style="height: 65px; overflow: auto" class="btn-group col-md-12">
                    <!-- The dnd-draggable directive makes an element draggable and will
                         transfer the object that was assigned to it. If an element was
                         dragged away, you have to remove it from the original list
                         yourself using the dnd-moved attribute -->

                    <div ng-repeat="item in list"
                        dnd-draggable="item"
                        dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)"
                        dnd-effect-allowed="move"
                        dnd-selected="scnListing.selected = item"
                        dnd-type="'containerType'"
                        ng-class="{'selected': scnListing.selected === item}"
                        class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
                        style="margin: 1px"
                        >
                        {{item}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove group from watchgroup , this will work

```
$scope.$watch(['yAxistm', 'chrtTyp', 'scnListing'], function(newval, oldval) {
    console.log('yAxistm val: ', newval[0]);
    console.log('chartTyp val: ', newval[1]);
    console.log('scenarios: ', newval[2]);
},true);
```

Comment: I tried that but without the group, `newval` comes back as undefined now...

Comment: posted pretty much everything except for what happens inside of the watchgroup since thats very long...

Comment: Secondly you are watching an array with variables try to create separate watch for array one